# How does one avoid Join placing a constraint on aggregate function?

Tags: postgresql, inner-join, aggregate-functions

[using postgres]

#### So the background to my scenario is:

I'm trying to get the average expenses by age where the user is active
cost = 40
Only 2 of the 33 year olds have purchased something
I have 34 active members that are 33 years old and active (whether or not they made a payment is irrelevant in this count)
with this in mind money spent per age = 40 / 34 = 1.18
what I am getting right now is = 40 / 2 = 20
I understand that it's constrained by the two users who made a purchase

#### So where did I get all of this?

```
select date_part('year', age(birthday)) as age, 
avg(cost) 
from person
inner join payment on person.person_id = payment.person_id
inner join product on payment.product_id = product.product_id
where 
date_part('year', age(birthday))= 33 and user_state = 'active'
group by age
```

Unfortunately, when using an aggregate function (in this example avg())
it seems avg() is constrained to the result of the inner join (I've tried a left join to maintain having access to all users, it didn't seem to work since I still got the undesired result 20). Is there a way to avoid this? In other words can I make it so the avg() call is specific to my person table rather than the result of the join?

If it matters, this is how I am retrieving total sum.

```
select sum(cost) 
from person
inner join payment on person.person_id = payment.person_id
inner join product on payment.product_id = product.product_id
where 
date_part('year', age(birthday))= 33 
and 
user_state = 'active'
```

= 40

The obvious is to do the count of people I want and then do the sum seperately, but I'm trying to avoid going from one query to another.

Comment: Please edit your post to use complete clear sentences. How do we parse your first sentence? What are "constrained by the two users" & "constrained to the result of the inner join"? You use "constrained" in a non-standard way to vaguely summarize what you have not explained. Same with "specific to my person table". What does "going from one query to another" mean? We can guess, from the correct solution, what you should have written, but you're not expressing it. But expressing yourself clearly is part of finding solutions. PS Add a column to the nested join for what you need outside it.

Answer (score 0):

`avg` will skip nulls so coalesce those null values into zeros and obviously left join:

```
select 
    date_part('year', age(birthday)) as age, 
    avg(coalesce(cost,0)) 
from 
    person
    left join 
    payment on ...
    left join
    product on ...
```